# SOAPUI MockService: WSDL Validation for parameters?

Tags: php, soapui

I configured with SoapUI 5.0 a MockService using a copy of this WSDL definition (http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL).

I cant test against the MockService with PHP SoapClient just fine:

```
        ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
        $client = new \SoapClient("http://172.20.1.52:8088/mockGlobalWeatherSoap?WSDL", array('trace' => 1));
        $response = $client->__soapCall('GetCitiesByCountry', array());
```

However, I started to play with the definition to ensure mandatory parameters for some methods.

For example, I wanted to ensure CountryName to be a mandatory parameters for the GetCitiesByCountry() method:

```
  <s:element name="GetCitiesByCountry">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CountryName" type="s:string" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
```

However, whatever I throw at SoapUI, my MockService will always send me a correct response diregarding whether the parameter has been provided or not.

How to ensure the basic validation as described in the WSDL file in SoapUi?

I tried the same thing from within SoapUI with sending a dummy soap request with missing parameters but SoapUI doesn't care and sends me a response back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SoapUI mocking does **not** simulate what is in the WSDL. It will only simulate a response. You have to configure SoapUI to simulate the specific response that you want.

Did you try the SoapUI documentation? http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/simulating-complex-behaviour.html

Comment: I didn't want to script complex behaviour, otherwise I might have looked at other solutions. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below script in the OnRequest script tab and it will validate the incoming request with your WSDL before sending the mocked response.

```js
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlValidator
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.mockoperation.WsdlMockRequestMessageExchange

def wsdlcontext = context.mockService.getMockedInterfaces()[0].getDefinitionContext() 
def validator = new WsdlValidator(wsdlcontext);

def operation = mockRequest.soapAction.substring(mockRequest.soapAction.lastIndexOf('/') +1)
log.info  context.mockService.toString() + "::" + operation
def wsdlMockOperation = context.mockService.getMockOperationByName(operation)
 
def msgExchange = new WsdlMockRequestMessageExchange(mockRequest, wsdlMockOperation); 
def errors = validator.assertRequest(msgExchange, false);

if (errors.length > 0 ) {
    log.error  context.mockService.toString() + "::" + operation + " Request Validation Failed"
     throw new Exception("VALIDATION ERRORS: " + errors.collect(){ '\n' + it })
}
```